# List of standard Java contracts

Tags: java, contract

I'm writing up a small series of tutorials for some friends of mine introducing them to Java. They're professional programmers, and good ones. Basically, our shop is running Progress 4GL (I just threw up a little) and we've inherited a simply awful code base. Our hope is to replace some of these poorly written modules with Java services at some point in the near future.

One thing that Java is big on is contracts. Is there a compiled list of the most common contracts in Java? I would expect things like equals contract to be on there.

Comment: Are you talking about design contracts or contracts that are runtime enforceable (design-by-contract)? If the latter, you should give Jass a try: http://modernjass.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html . There is a similar effort for the .NET languages, should you end up swinging that way: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With java, implementing the java.lang.Object is about the basest contract there is... since everything is an Object (except intrinsic types).

That said: I work for Progress.  Give our support folks a call - we're very Java friendly.

Comment: Progess is most definitely Java friendly. A medium term goal, however, is to reduce licensing costs across the board, and this means moving to more "open-sourcey" platforms. About the contracts though, I'm aware of a couple just in Object, and there's more in the Collections library. I was just hoping someone had already pre-compiled a list of the most common ones. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your friends are professional programmers and you want them learn the best practices early, have them read [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) by Joshua Bloch and save your time.

Comment: I've read the book before, and already went out and bought a copy, and plan to reference it heavily.